# Disabling and Enabling Shutdown on demand

Tags: winapi, shutdown, group-policy

I want to disable or enable `Shutdown`,`Restart`,`Hibernate`, and `Sleep` options in the start menu of Windows XP/7 programmatically and on demand (immediately).

Using `gpedit.msc` tool and setting `Remove and prevent access to Shut Down command` to `Enabled`/`Disabled` affects the start menu imediately and these options are shown/hidden as I want. But I cannot write a program to do this.

I found one programmatic solution that is creating `NoAction` variable with value `1` placed in this registry path:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

But this does not disable the Shutdown/etc immediately and affects **after** the `explorer.exe` is restarted.

I also tried notifying `explorer.exe` with [RefreshPolicyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [RefreshPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and broadcasting `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and `WM_WININICHANGE`, but none of these informed explorer to re-read the registry/policies.

I guess using [Group Policy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be a good solution but don't know how to use it. Can you give me a simple code for applying a local group policy with Group Policy API?

Or, Do you know any other way to enable/disable shutdown/etc immediately and programmatically?

**Note:** The target platforms are **Windows XP** and **Windows 7**